# Tracking SA login in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: database-connection, database-performance, database-administration

Suppose few applications are connecting SQL Server using SA login. Is there any way we can find out whether the SA login attempted has been used by applications or anyone manually who knows the password? Can we able to differentiate or track SA login with its details(application or manually) using triggers and SQL scripts? Your help will be greatly appreciated!!

Thanks in advance!!

Regards
Mohan

Comment: You should ***never ever*** use the `sa` account for production work!

Comment: Hi Marc, yes you are absolutely correct but this was done by other DBA folks  a long back when they developed the system. So is there any possible track to find which application the SA login attempt is happening?

Comment: SImple: disable the `sa` account and see what's crashing :-)